# Optimizepress: Unwanted newline when input is inside paragraph tag

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have the following code on my server:

```
<p>This is a test to determine why the <input type="text" style="text-align: center;" value="input"/> element is created on a new line when on a wordpress page.</p>
```

This produces what I want to see - no line breaks:

[image: This is what I want to see, no line breaks]

However, on my wordpress site using Optimizepress "custom HTML element" this produces line breaks before and after input element:

[image: Line breaks before and after input element]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code that you have provided will generate the output as you expect it. However, there are chances that some other css properties are being applied to input tag.

You can inspect element and check the property that is being applied to it. In wordpress, when we save our page, many a times the structure change. So do re check.

Please provide more information if you want me to go indepth. Hope this resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up playing with the [margin], [padding] and [display] settings by including them in the elements style. It was the [display: inline] that seemed to do it.

```
<p>This is a test to determine why the 
<input type="text" style="text-align: center; width: 100px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; 
display: inline;" value="input"/> 
element is created on a new line when on a wordpress page.</p>
```